# Word that includes "food, alcoholic drinks, and non-alcoholic drinks"?

Tags: word-request, food

I searched Thesaurus but found [nothing](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cuisine).

Example sentence:

> The __ were top quality, just like the restaurant
>   review assured.

Comment: Maybe use **menu** instead?

Comment: "Food and beverages" is probably as close as you can get.

Comment: Or ingestibles ...

Comment: Instead of trying to fill this blank with a single word, I'd suggest something like "Everything we tried".

Comment: Literally, "consumables" has this meaning but nobody expects that meaning anymore.

Comment: Sustenance or Victuals (vittles - old english form) from http://english.stackexchange.com/q/49358/11892

Comment: Although it doesn't incliude drinks, I liek to use the word `viands` https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/viand - just to enlarge your vocabulary

Comment: "Refreshments" is a commonly used word for the above. Also "Food" covers food and drinks in a lot of situations.

Comment: @Anton - Most people would consider "refreshments" to be light snacks and/or drinks, not a meal.

Comment: @Johnny Exactly...That was the question after all :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There isn't really a single word in regular usage that covers food and drink combined.

**Food and beverages** is probably the most common term in the hotel trade, however outside the trade the expression **food and drink** is much more widely used: see this [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=food+and+beverages%2Cfood+and+drink%2C+food+and+drinks&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfood%20and%20beverages%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfood%20and%20drink%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfood%20and%20drinks%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cfood%20and%20drink%3B%2Cc0).

Note that, when used in this expression, **drink** is normally considered as a collective term, so it is not plural. The plural can also be used, but it is less common.

Comment: be careful, in many contexts "drinks" can be implied as alcoholic beverages".  For example, "Let's go out to dinner and have a couple of drinks".  In the context you listed "The menu was top quality", "The food and drinks were top quality", "The restaurant fare was top quality", or  "The food and bar were top quality" would be appropriate American English phrases.

Comment: @JonMilliken, that's certainly a possible interpretation, but it's not the first one in the Cambridge Dictionary http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/drink or the Oxford Dictionary https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/drink or Merriam-Webster https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drink or dictionary.com  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/drink?s=t The OP wanted to include alcoholic drinks anyway.

Comment: you are certainly correct. However, in (at least American) English "drink(s)" in this context implies alcohol.  "I'm going to the store to grab some drinks" and "lets go out and grab some drinks" have a vastly different meaning. The first, I'd expect water, juice, milk, maybe a case of beer.  The second means "Lets go to the bar"

Comment: JavaLatte is correct; the industry term is "Food and Beverage", and a derivative is "Food, Beverage and Hospitality".  If there _were_ a handy term combining the two, all of these related industries would be very likely to use it, if only to save print ink and signage/logo real estate.

Answer (score 48):

**Fare** as described at [dictonary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fare) (and [english.se](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/49456)) is a slightly older word, but you will still find it at many restaurants.

Note that fare is a singular, collective noun.  The phrase would read:

> The fare was top quality, just like the restaurant review assured.

Comment: This sounds probably the most natural and fitting of all the suggestions so far, to me (British English). It certainly seems to appear in reviews https://www.google.co.uk/search?espv=2&q=top+quality+fare&oq=top+quality+fare&gs_l=serp.3...14460.14460.0.14559.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.0.0.McdG3Jna5Ms

Comment: I think it's because I'm American, but maybe because I'm young... I've never heard that word used in that sense.  Only as something you pay a bus or cab driver.

Comment: Certainly fairly common in the UK, but generally considered a little "old world", although perhaps not as much as "repast" which you'd struggle to find in a restaurant.

Answer (score 26):

The words **comestibles**, **victuals**, **provisions** and **foodstuffs** are occasionally used in a generic sense to mean "things providing nourishment", including both food and drink. They certainly aren't common words though, and probably aren't perfect for your sentence. If you absolutely have to use a single word, the first two are in my opinion most suitable, although they may be considered rather old-fashioned and pretentious.

Comment: The first word that sprang into my head was "`comestibles`"

Comment: Nobody who has seen the Monty Python cheese shop sketch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3KBuQHHKx0 could **ever** take the word comestibles seriously. Note the keyword **humorous** in this definition. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/comestible

Comment: Note also the regionally-used abbreviation of "victuals", "vittles".

Answer (score 16):

**Offerings** is a commercial term occasionally seen in marketing verbiage. [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/offering?s=t) defines offerings as "something presented for inspection or sale."

> The **offerings** were top quality, just like the restaurant review assured.

Using any other food or meal term simply feels forced and over encompassing.

Comment: I like this one, it even works for cannibals!

Comment: Offerings to me sounds like a libation or other offering to some deity. But maybe I'm just reading the wrong books. :)

Answer (score 14):

If the food and drink isn't the primary reason for being where they are served, you could say **refreshments**.

Comment: I think 'refreshments' is a good option, but I usually associate refreshments with food and drink that is provided by a host and not what I order at a restaurant. *The refreshments at the conference were top notch, even though the presentations weren't very good.* I usually say "meal" when talking about a restaurant - *Our meals were top quality, just like the restaurant review assured.*

Answer (score 4):

For the sentence and context in the question, I'd simply go with **meal** or **food**.  The "drink" part of a restaurant meal is usually secondary unless you're a bit of a wine connoisseur.

Comment: "The "drink" part of a restaurant meal is usually secondary" I feel sad for you

Answer (score 3):

Although it doesn't always refer to food and drink, I think the most natural word to insert in your example sentence is "selections":

> The selections were top quality, just like the restaurant review assured.

Although it would probably be better to use "selection" and change "were" to "was":

> The selection was top quality, just like the restaurant review assured.

It's obviously food, because we're talking about a restaurant.

From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/selection):

> 3. an aggregate of things displayed for choice, purchase, use, etc.; a group from which a choice may be made:
>      *The store had a wide selection of bracelets.*